# KeyVault reference not working for Linux Python Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Trying to use KeyVault Secret from Linux Python Azure Function.  The problem is that the Function is not resolving the reference.  I'm expecting the secret in the logs but it's printing the literal @Microsoft.Keyvault(...) instead.
[image]

---

**Configuration**

1. System Identity is enabled on the Azure Function.
   [image]
2. This Identity has full access to the KeyVault.
   [image]
3. The KV secret is mapped to the Function Configuration
   [image]

I'm stalled with my development at this point.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

---

**Edit**

Working with Azure support and managed to isolate the problem with Linux Functions with Consumption Plan.  It works if using a Premium Plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with Azure Functions Linux Apps.  SecretUri does not resolve with a Consumption Plan, but works with a Premium Plan.

The workaround is to use **@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[];SecretName[])** instead.  This resolves properly with Consumption Plan.  See this issue log for more information:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2248